# Where can I locate taconomy.txt file for CUB Dataset

Tags: dataset, cub

I'm working on some replication and I need to use taxonomy.txt file for CUB Dataset. Can anyone point me to the repo of this file? Thank you.

Comment: Can you indicate what you've tried so far? Where have you looked?

Comment: I already looked in the github repository of task2vec. So far, I can not locate two files namely taxonomy.txt and passeriformes.txt.